# What happens if you start too many threads?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, processor

What happens when you create too many threads? Does it cause the CPU to crash or is there some sort of internal load balancing mechanism on Windows OS'?

I'm running the following code:

```
private async void A(string[] a)
{
    var tasks = a.Select(B);
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task B(string b)
{
    new Thread(async delegate ()
    {
        //all the work that needs to be done

    }).Start();
}
```

I'm running an array of async Tasks but within each async method I've encapsulated all the work that needs to be done in a new thread. What happens if I call B a large number of times? How will the processor deal with too many threads?

Comment: That might very much depend on "all the work that needs to be done".

Comment: It is the job of the operating system to decide what the processor should work on.  How many threads you can create is throttled by the usual resource, [it is memory](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/).  A number that is far, far higher than the number that a programmer can debug.  The usual dust-off applies: If you need to know then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: The short answer: if you start too many threads, performance will tank, both for your application and the rest of the system.

Comment: This article has some interesting related information: [The Old New Thing: Does Windows have a limit of 2000 threads per process?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050729-14/?p=34773/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, why do you run Threads from within Tasks? In 99.9% cases it just does not make sense. In the remaining 0.1% it maaybe makes a tiny bit of sense, but you most probably should be using a TaskCompletionSource instead of a Task.

Tasks were designed so that you can have schedulers which will queue those tasks, monitor when these task sleep/wait/etc and reuse threads to run other tasks in the meantime..

Basically, you wrap your "work" into tasks, and then you give those tasks to the scheduler(s) and then schedulers decide if, when, and how many threads to run to execute these tasks.

Schedulers are not magic, and they don't have a crystal ball to predict future. I said that they "decide", but that's half true only: the scheduler usually follow some general rules depending on its kind. So, you choose right scheduler for your fantasy and done.

Seriously, drop that current approach. Use schedulers instead. You can even have a scheduler that will execute each task on separate thread. It will be equivalent to your current approach. But then, you will be able to quickly switch to another scheduler and feel the difference.

Here's a couple of resources for you, a VERY important library:

- [lots of additional types of schedulers working out of the box](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/09/parallelextensionsextras-tour-7-additional-taskschedulers/)
- [into to the library that provides them](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/04/a-tour-of-parallelextensionsextras/)
- [nuget with that lib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ParallelExtensionsExtras/)

Seriously. If you don't want to read/etc, then just take the first article and read just the **names** of the different scheduler to at least get an idea of how many possibilities you choose to ignore.

Finally, answering to the question, yes, Windows is somewhat load-balanced. It will try to defend against running too many threads. It will actually run a small amount of threads (more-or-less equal to the number of logical execution units in your processor(s)) at given point of time, and rest of them will sleep and wait for their time. Windows will switch between them ocassionally, so you will observe that as if all of them were running, but some of them slower, some of them faster.

However, it does NOT mean that you can create an unlimited amount of threads. Obviously, there's a memory limit: if you have X GB of ram, you can't keep more of them than you can fit in the memory. I'm joking a little right now, but since there's some obvious limit, there will be more limits. However, there is a bit of seriousness here, because, you see, each thread has a STACK, and that stack can be in order of megabytes, so if you've got 32bits processor, the number of STACKs can reach several thousands at most. So.. yes, memory can be a limit. It's less apparent on 64bit, but, surely, you don't have enough RAM to fill whole 64bit address space, so on 64bit you will have a limit too.

Since Windows will try to keep records of all threads, even those sleeping ones, it will waste time on tracking these records. Also, it will waste time on switching, because as an OS, it will try to keep them all swwitching and running. It directly means that the more threads you create (1/10/100/1000/..) everything will run slower - and more slowly than just divided by N threads (not: 1/0.1/0.01/0.001/.., but: 1/0.1/0.097/0.0089/..) because of the time wasted on keeping records and on switching.

Threads also have priorities. Internal system threads often have higher priority. System will switch to them more often than to yours, this means that the more threads you run, even slower your app will process.

There's also a hard limit. For tracking important objects, Windows uses a concept of "handles". Each window, each thread, each shared memory block, each opened file stream, etc, as long as it is alive (and a bit longer) - has a unique handle. You can actually **STARVE** windows by using up all handles.

For example, if you use up all GUI handles, you wont be able to open new windows. Or window regions. Or controls. Imagine opening a Notepad which starts up and shows no Menu and no TextArea because there were not enough free handles to assign them to.

Due to that limit, Windows actually limits the number of allocated handles per-process. It means that, say, Windows has a pool of 1M handles, but every process can use only up to 1K. Those numbers are artificial, just so you get an idea.

Since physical (native) thread has to have a handle, here's another limit.

I'm not a real expert on that matter, let's so fall back to a series of articles written by experts, they covert there thread limits, handle limits, and much more:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/07/05/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-processes-and-threads/

Answer (score 5):

The CPU only executes what the OS tells it to, the OS is [in charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) of which threads run and how long they run before they are interrupted. There is some anti-starvation built into the scheduler so it should never completely lock the system but you can probably almost bring it to its knees if you just keep spawning as many threads as possible until you run out of memory or address space.

If we pretend that your program is the only program running then the ideal number of threads is the same as the number of CPU cores if the task is CPU limited. If the task is I/O limited or needs to wait on kernel objects then more threads might be ideal.

If you create thousands of threads then you will waste time context switching between them and your work will take longer to complete. Instead of manually starting new threads you should use the [thread pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/threading/how-to-use-a-thread-pool) to perform your work so Windows itself can balance the optimum number of threads.

`await` and other high level asynchronous keywords probably already use the thread pool.

Comment: Yes, in fact these use thread pool by default, but in fact `await` and friends are based on `Task`s (not `Thread`s), so it's possible to make them use whatever TaskScheduler you want. Actually, Tasks are much easier to use and easily configurable, and also much lighter than threads, so in .Net context you usually shouldn't touch 'Threads' or the Pool until you want to create your own scheduler for some reason.. and with the ParallelExtensionsExtras library and with its smorgasbord of schedulers, it's not that likely that you will have to write a new one. Ah yes, I speak from the Desktop POV...

Comment: Correct except for the `await` statement. [Truly asynchronous code does not block a thread at all](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary: what do you refer to? Nobody said that await blocks.. (though it can deadlock sometimes :P) Did you mean Anders's last line? `await` splits the method into 'head' and one/several 'continuations', and while the former runs on caller thread, the latter does not have to and may run on any context you configure them to - original caller, thread pool, your own scheduler - so saying "await uses threadpool" isn't strictly incorrect. It's just imprecise and only part of the full story behind. Or do you refer or something else?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl: I'm referring to the last line in the answer. The idea that `await` just blocks a thread pool thread is a common misconception. Also, the `Task`s created by `async` (and most of the tasks consumed by `await`) do not have anything to do with `TaskScheduler`s.

Comment: @StephenCleary: where in `await and other high level asynchronous keywords probably already use the thread pool.` do you see any statement that it blocks? You've said "correct except" and I'm asking about that words.

Answer (score 1):

Threads do have significant costs - VERY roughly - imagine 100K bytes per thread (they each need a stack for one thing), and they each place a slight burdon on operating system components (e.g. scheduler) which have to manage them all.

Threads DO present a very simple model for managing async tasks. I'm a big fan of that approach.

But if you are going to use a lot of threads, please consider using thread pools as a way to re-use the underlying thread objects (while having lots of runnables - just not running).

And - since you are using C#, async tasks (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) are a more efficient stategy to consider.

Often though - simplicity of implementation matters more than efficiency (up to a point). What you described with a thread-pool (to throttle actual thread count) may work fine.